# make workspace 2x2 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: gnome, compiz, workspaces

I would like to use 2x2 workspaces.

I am heavily used to it and after I bought a new notebook and installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit with GNOME, it just doesn't work.

I installed compiz manager and tried a few suggestions I found out on the internet, but nothing work.

I tried setting only 1 desktop and hoped compiz would handle those 4 viewports, but it didn't happen.

I tried setting compiz desktop size-> horizontal and vertical size to 2 and 2.

This is my compiz manager:

[image]
Thanks for any suggestions on how to get 2x2 workspaces working.

Comment: Gnome Shell uses Mutter instead of Compiz so CompizConfig settings won't work unless you switch to Unity desktop or use Compiz with XFCE or another DE.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on workspaces in the bottom right corner of the screen and select Preferences. There you can set "Show all workspaces in 2 rows" and you will get 2x2 layout.

Comment: This solution also works with little change in Xubuntu (XFCE) — clicking on the workspaces symbol on the panel, select `properties` and change `number of rows` as desired.

Answer (score 0):

The setting to enable workspaces should be in System Settings>Appearance>Behavior

Comment: I don't have appearance nor behavior there. http://i.imgur.com/SyzFYxW.png

Comment: Oh, right - GNOME. It should be in "Background"

Comment: there is only wallpaper and screen saver image settings. :(