# How to have multiple desktops?

Tags: xubuntu

I've installed Xubuntu 16.04 on my new laptop and I don't have multiple desktops and desktop switcher also <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ARROWS</kbd> shortcuts don't work.

Comment: Multiple desktops are  like multiple workspaces

Comment: Once you have multiple desktops, let's say 4, you may want to order them into a 2x2 configuration instead of the standard 1x4. Take a look to my commentary for Xubuntu here ;)  https://askubuntu.com/questions/512155/make-workspace-2x2-on-ubuntu-14-04-1-lts#735569

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus that's how I have it configured.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to specify the required number of desktops in **System Settings => Workspaces**, after add the desktop switcher to your panel.

Answer (score 5):

You can make by following below steps on Ubuntu 16.04:

1. **System Settings** → ***Appearance***

   [image: System Settings]
2. **Appearance** → ***Behaviour***

   [image: Appearance]
3. enable workspaces option.